# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'iface'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have assigned one method to combobox like this

```
def run(self):

    """Run method that performs all the real work"""
    GetAllLayers(self)
    #attach index changed event / passing parametrized method
    self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda arg=self:  LayersValueChange(arg))
```

getting error here

```
def LayersValueChange(self):
    print "abc"
    #selectedLayerName = str(self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentText())
    #selectedLayerName = self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentText()

    layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()//here error
```

And Error is:

> layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
>   AttributeError:
>   'int' object has no attribute 'iface'

self is object but it getting it like int.

Comment: Did you use the **Plugin Builder** to create your plugin? If not, make sure your _mainPlugin.py_ file contains the correct reference to `iface` as described [here](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html#mainplugin-py).

Comment: i guess there problem in registering function on currentIndexChange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the answer through [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39874087/parameterized-function-for-connect/39897470#39897470). I connecting method wrongly correct syntax is:

```
 self.dlg.cbLayerNamesAll.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: LayersValueChange(self))
```